# Java parse text file and get all words between word and character

Tags: java, string, file

I am trying to write java code to parse a text file and get all the words present between a word and a character.

Using the text below I need to get all the words between the word "commercial" and the character "|". In this case the correct output would be bot, real, insurance, and veil.

```
  /tony/ |
  /adam/ /real/ /farce/ |
  /boat/ /rds/ /dbb/ /Pilot/ /Registry/ |
  /commercial/ /bot/ /real/ /insurance/ /veil/ |
  /commerce/ /health/ /insurance/ /yes/ |  
  /Clalit/ /Health/ |
  /congenital/ /anomaly/ |
  /Danish/ /beef/ /street/ | /Danish/ /bee/  | /no/ 
  /registry/ |
  /car/ | /Danish/ /spot/ |
```

I am new to java and have tried writing java code but I am not getting anything close to it.

```
public static void parseText() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    //String fullDatabaseNameString = "";

    String line;

    try (
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("text.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Do your thing with line
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for (String s : words) {
                String wordStripped = s.replace("/", "");

                if (wordStripped.equals("Danish")) {

                    if (wordStripped.equals("|")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Also, do you need to keep track of new lines? Also, I don't see how this is the correct output, since there's stop char after bot

Comment: @AlexeySoshin added the code done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to solve your problem, here is a simple solution :

```
String content = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();//<----(1)

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( Pattern.quote("commercial") 
 + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("|"));//<-----(2)
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
String[] result;
while (matcher.find()) {
   result = matcher.group(1).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").trim().split("\\s+");//<--(3)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

---

- (1) read all the content of the file in one string
- (2) use this regex `commercial(.*?)\\|` to get every thing between `(commercial and |)`
- (3) replace every thing not an alphanumirique or space with empty so you can extract just the word then use split with `\s+` to get word by word, for your input the output is :

**Output**

```
[bot, real, insurance, veil]
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you said you are new to Java. are you new to programming in general? I'll try to guide you to making your own solution using common tool like an array of strings, files parsing and string compare.

You have the right idea. First of all you should think about what do you want to do. You have your task laid out clearly.

> get all the words between the word "commercial" and the character "|"

That is great! Now we need to figure out how to approach this. We have this file :

```
  /tony/ |
  /adam/ /real/ /farce/ |
  /boat/ /rds/ /dbb/ /Pilot/ /Registry/ |
  /commercial/ /bot/ /real/ /insurance/ /veil/ |
  /commerce/ /health/ /insurance/ /yes/ |  
  /Clalit/ /Health/ |
  /congenital/ /anomaly/ |
  /Danish/ /beef/ /street/ | /Danish/ /bee/  | /no/ 
  /registry/ |
  /car/ | /Danish/ /spot/ |
```

Now as you said you know the answer to this. You should get bot, real, insurance and veil.
Now you got the file opening right. You need to tell your program where to look. now where your code gets a bit lost is what you are trying to do here. How do you want to approach this? looking at it for a few seconds, I would scan each character. if you see a "/" Start your word. put each character you get into a string until you see a "/" again. that could be an array of strings.

There are ways you can do this in a few lines, put I assume you are new to programming and maybe you haven't learn pattern and such. so lets stick with basic.

Next, you look for the character "|". You could store it as its own word in your array. this will be your guide for line change.

When you are finished parsing the file, you will have a one dimensional array where you will have a word at each index. then it only a matter of comparing the array with your word, and iterate until you see the "|" while printing them.

there are simpler ways, but I find this to be very methodical and great learning tool.

Here is what I mean using your code to start.

```
package so;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Fileparser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        parseText();

    }

    public static void parseText() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // String fullDatabaseNameString = "";

        String line;

        try (
                InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Dev\\workspace\\so\\src\\so\\file.txt");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            ) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] words = line.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    if(words[i].equals("/commercial/")) {
                        i++;
                        while(!words[i].equals("|")) {
                            System.out.print(words[i]);
                            i++; //Don't forget to check your index to be sure you are never out of bounds! Not done here.
                            //You can also remove the "/" caracter if needed.
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!
**Output**

```
/bot//real//insurance//veil/
```